# Problems to label nodes in a particular force layout D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made an algorithm with D3 to vizualize some datas. The algorithm is doing what i'm expecting of him. He separates nodes in multiple focis with the Force layout, links and nodes appears and disappears dynamicaly.

The problems comes with the labeling of the nodes. D3 seems to do the work but multiples times for each nodes (when i look at it with firebug).

Here is my code :

```
var actions = [
{"action":"arrivee","id":"001","service":1},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"002","service":1},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"003","service":1},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"004","service":1},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"005","service":1},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"006","service":3},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"007","service":3},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"008","service":3},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"009","service":3},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"010","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"011","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"012","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"013","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"014","service":4},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"015","service":4},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"016","service":4},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"017","service":4},
{"action":"contact","id":"0","source":"001","target":"017"},
{"action":"contact","id":"1","source":"016","target":"012"},
{"action":"contact","id":"2","source":"004","target":"011"},
{"action":"contact","id":"3","source":"001","target":"010"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"0"},
{"action":"depart","id":"017"},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"018","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"019","service":1},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"020","service":1},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"021","service":0},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"022","service":0},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"023","service":0},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"024","service":0},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"025","service":0},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"026","service":0},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"027","service":3},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"028","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"029","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"030","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"031","service":2},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"032","service":4},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"033","service":4},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"034","service":4},
{"action":"arrivee","id":"035","service":4},
{"action":"contact","id":"4","source":"013","target":"002"},
{"action":"contact","id":"5","source":"009","target":"008"},
{"action":"contact","id":"6","source":"005","target":"007"},
{"action":"contact","id":"7","source":"009","target":"014"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"7"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"6"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"5"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"4"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"3"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"2"},
{"action":"fincontact","id":"1"},
{"action":"depart","id":"016"},
{"action":"depart","id":"015"},
{"action":"depart","id":"014"},
{"action":"depart","id":"013"},
{"action":"depart","id":"012"},
{"action":"depart","id":"011"},
{"action":"depart","id":"010"},
{"action":"depart","id":"009"},
{"action":"depart","id":"008"},
{"action":"depart","id":"007"},
{"action":"depart","id":"006"},
{"action":"depart","id":"005"},
{"action":"depart","id":"004"},
{"action":"depart","id":"003"},
{"action":"depart","id":"002"},
{"action":"depart","id":"018"},
{"action":"depart","id":"019"},
{"action":"depart","id":"020"},
{"action":"depart","id":"021"},
{"action":"depart","id":"022"},
{"action":"depart","id":"023"},
{"action":"depart","id":"024"},
{"action":"depart","id":"025"},
{"action":"depart","id":"026"},
{"action":"depart","id":"027"},
{"action":"depart","id":"028"},
{"action":"depart","id":"029"},
{"action":"depart","id":"030"},
{"action":"depart","id":"031"},
{"action":"depart","id":"032"},
{"action":"depart","id":"033"},
{"action":"depart","id":"034"},
{"action":"depart","id":"035"},
{"action":"depart","id":"001"}]

var vv = window,
w = vv.innerWidth,
h = vv.innerHeight;

var rmax = 30;
foci = [{x: 500, y: 150}, {x: 200, y: 500}, {x: 700, y: 500}, {x: 400, y: 700}, {x: 600, y: 700}];
//canevas selection
var svg = d3.select("#animviz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
var fill = d3.scale.category10();
//link and node class creation
svg.append("g").attr("class", "links");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");

 //to know if the graphs are up to date
var uptodate = true;
var nIntervId;
//containers de noeuds et liens
var nodes = [], links = [];

 var force = d3.layout.force()
                 .nodes(nodes)
                 .links(links)
                 .size([w, h])
                 .friction(0.9)
                 .charge(-50)
                 .gravity(0.02)
                 .linkDistance(50)
                 .charge(-500)
                 .on("tick", tick);

 var iter = 0;

var node = svg.select(".nodes").selectAll(".node");
var link = svg.select(".links").selectAll(".link");
//repeat an action every "interval"
var interval = 0.2;

 nIntervId = setInterval(function() {

var action = readData();
addData(action);
if(!uptodate){
    update();
}

}, interval*1000);

function addData(action) {

uptodate = false;
switch(action.action) {
case "arrivee":
    nodes.push({id: action.id, service: action.service});
    break;

case "depart":
    for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(nodes[i].id == action.id){
            nodes.splice(i, 1);
        }
    };
    break;

case "contact":
    var source;
    var target;

    for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(nodes[i].id == action.source){
            source = nodes[i];
        }
        if(nodes[i].id == action.target){
            target = nodes[i];
        }
    };
    links.push({source:source, target:target, id:action.id});
    break;

case "fincontact":
    for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(links[i].id == action.id){
            links.splice(i, 1);
        }
    };
    break;

default:
    uptodate = true;
} 
}

 function readData(){

var n = iter;
iter++;
var data = actions[n];
return data;

}

function update() {
force.start();
link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id+"-"+d.target.id; });
link.enter()
.append("line")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("stroke", "#ccc")
.attr("stroke-width", 2);
link.exit().remove();

var r = d3.scale.sqrt()
.domain(d3.extent(force.nodes(), function(d) {return d.weight; }))
.range([15, rmax]);

node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id; });
node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .style("stroke-width", "10")
    .style("fill", "white")//function(d, i) { return fill(d.service ); })
    .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(i & 1 ? "red" : "green") })

node.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .text(function(d) {return d.id});

node.exit().remove();
}

function tick(e) {

var k = 0.5 * e.alpha;
nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.y += (foci[o.service].y - o.y) * k;
    o.x += (foci[o.service].x - o.x) * k;
});

link.attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;})
    .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;})
    .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;})
    .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;});
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(rmax, Math.min(w - rmax, d.x)); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(rmax, Math.min(h - rmax, d.y)); });
 }
```

readData() read the dataframe, addData() is a big loop to have dynamical moves and update() is the D3 part where is my attempt to label my nodes.

I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks you.

Comment: `text-anchor` is not a valid SVG element. Append a `text` element and then set the `text-anchor` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, i'll update my code.

Comment: You also want to set the `transform` attribute for `node` and not `cx` and `cy` (which won't do anything). As for the original problem, it's not obvious to me why this would happen.

Comment: Thank you for helping, i'll post my new code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of searches i'm able to post the working code as an answer.

```
var actions = [
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"001","service":1},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"002","service":1},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"003","service":1},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"004","service":1},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"005","service":1},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"006","service":3},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"007","service":3},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"008","service":3},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"009","service":3},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"010","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"011","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"012","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"013","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"014","service":4},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"015","service":4},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"016","service":4},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"017","service":4},
    {"action":"contact","id":"0","source":"001","target":"017"},
    {"action":"contact","id":"1","source":"016","target":"012"},
    {"action":"contact","id":"2","source":"004","target":"011"},
    {"action":"contact","id":"3","source":"001","target":"010"},
  {"action":"fincontact","id":"0"},
  {"action":"depart","id":"017"},
  {"action":"arrivee","id":"018","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"019","service":1},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"020","service":1},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"021","service":0},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"022","service":0},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"023","service":0},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"024","service":0},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"025","service":0},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"026","service":0},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"027","service":3},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"028","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"029","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"030","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"031","service":2},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"032","service":4},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"033","service":4},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"034","service":4},
    {"action":"arrivee","id":"035","service":4},
    {"action":"contact","id":"4","source":"013","target":"002"},
    {"action":"contact","id":"5","source":"009","target":"008"},
    {"action":"contact","id":"6","source":"005","target":"007"},
    {"action":"contact","id":"7","source":"009","target":"014"},
    {"action":"fincontact","id":"7"},
    {"action":"fincontact","id":"6"},
    {"action":"fincontact","id":"5"},
    {"action":"fincontact","id":"4"},
    {"action":"fincontact","id":"3"},
    {"action":"fincontact","id":"2"},
    {"action":"fincontact","id":"1"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"016"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"015"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"014"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"013"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"012"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"011"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"010"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"009"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"008"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"007"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"006"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"005"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"004"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"003"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"002"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"018"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"019"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"020"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"021"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"022"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"023"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"024"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"025"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"026"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"027"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"028"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"029"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"030"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"031"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"032"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"033"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"034"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"035"},
    {"action":"depart","id":"001"}]

var vv = window,
    w = vv.innerWidth,
    h = vv.innerHeight;

foci = [{x: 500, y: 150}, {x: 200, y: 500}, {x: 700, y: 500}, {x: 400, y: 700}, {x: 600, y: 700}];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var links = [], nodes = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
           .nodes(nodes)
           .links(links)
           .size([w, h])
           .friction(0.9)
           .charge(-50)
           .gravity(0.02)
           .linkDistance(50)
           .charge(-500)
           .on("tick", tick);

var link;
var node;

var iter = 0;
var interval = 0.2;
var uptodate = true;
var nIntervId;

 nIntervId = setInterval(function() {
  //alert("je passe");
  var action = readData();
  addData(action);
  if(!uptodate){
    update();
  }

}, interval*1000);

function addData(action) {

uptodate = false;
  switch(action.action) {
    case "arrivee":
        nodes.push({id: action.id, service: action.service});
        break;

    case "depart":
        for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if(nodes[i].id == action.id){
            nodes.splice(i, 1);
          }
        };
        break;

    case "contact":
      var source;
      var target;

      for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(nodes[i].id == action.source){
          source = nodes[i];
        }
        if(nodes[i].id == action.target){
          target = nodes[i];
        }
      };
        links.push({source:source, target:target, id:action.id});
        break;

    case "fincontact":
        for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if(links[i].id == action.id){
            links.splice(i, 1);
          }
        };
        break;

    default:
        uptodate = true;
  } 

}

function readData(){

  var n = iter;
  iter++;
  var data = actions[n];
  return data;

}

function update(){
  force.start();

  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(force.links());

  link.enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(force.nodes());
  node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);


  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 20)
      .style("stroke-width", "10")
      .style("fill", "white")//function(d, i) { return fill(d.service ); })
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(i & 1 ? "red" : "green") });

  node.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id });

  node.exit().remove();

}


function tick(e) {


    var k = 0.5 * e.alpha;
    nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
        o.y += (foci[o.service].y - o.y) * k;
        o.x += (foci[o.service].x - o.x) * k;
    });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
};
```

Thank you for helping.